# Concatenate a large number of files line for line in python

Tags: python, file-io, concatenation

thanks for lending your eyes here.

I'm processing some spectral data that is in the form of several hundred text files (1.txt,2.txt,3.txt ...) and they are all formatted with the exact same number of lines like this:
For clarity:

```
1.txt:             2.txt:            3.txt:
1,5                1,4               1,7
2,8                2,9               2,14
3,10               3,2               3,5
4,13               4,17              4,9
<...>              <...>             <...>
4096,1             4096,7            4096,18
```

I'm attempting to concatenate them line-by-line so at I walk away with one output file like:

```
5,4,7
8,9,14
10,2,5
13,17,9
<...>
1,7,18
```

I'm very new to Python, and I'd really appreciate some help here. I've attempted this mess:

```
howmanyfiles=8
output=open('output.txt','w+')
for j in range(howmanyfiles):
    fp=open(str(j+1) + '.txt','r')
    if j==0:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            splitline=line.split(",")
            output.write(splitline[1])
    else:
        output.close()
        output=open('output.txt','r+')
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            splitline=line.split(",")
            output.write(output.readline(i)[:-1]+","+splitline[1])
    fp.close()
output.close()
```

My line of thinking in the above is that I need to place the cursor back at the beginning of the document for each file.. but it's really blowing up in my face.

Thanks dearly.

-matt

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get a lot of mileage out of the `zip` built-in function, which will let you iterate over all the input files at the same time:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

num_files = 8
with open("output.txt", "w") as output, ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open("{}.txt".format(i+1)))
             for i in range(num_files)]
    for lines in zip(*files): # lines is a tuple with one line from each file
        new_line = ",".join(line.partition(',')[2] for line in lines) + "\n"
        file.write(new_line)
```

Comment: you might mean `line.partition(',')[2]`. To close files properly,[`ExitStack` could be used](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: thanks for those suggestions. I've added them both. The `split` call was simply an oversight, but I'd deliberately skipped the context manager stuff because I expected it to be confusing. `ExitStack` is much easier to use than I had anticipated, which is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way to do it with generators:

```
import sys

files     = sys.argv[1:]
handles   = (open(f) for f in files)
readers   = ((line.strip() for line in h) for h in handles)
splitters = ((line.split(',')[1] for line in r) for r in readers)
joiners   = (",".join(tuple(s)) for s in splitters)

for j in joiners:
    print j
```

You might also look into the Unix [paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_%28Unix%29) command

Comment: I made some minor changes here, but it's coming all out at once-- how would I introduce newline returns?
   `import sys
    files = sys.argv[1:]
    handles = (open(f) for f in files)
    readers = ((line.split(",")[1][:-1] for line in h) for h in handles)
    joiners = (",".join(r) for r in readers)

    for j in joiners:
        print(j)`